# On VBA Access, how to see if we have printed a Report to a Physical Printer but not on the Screen as Preview?

Tags: vba, ms-access, report

In an Access Application mydb.accdb, a Report is used to print invoice.
The orders are recorded in the table `tblMainOrders` with a DateTime column .DatePrinted,
to follow the last printed date time. This way we can see if we've sent the order to the supplier by email with a pdf document as joint piece, created by PDFCreator.

This date is set during the Report.Close() event, checking [.CurrentView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.report.currentview)
with the code:

```
Private Sub Report_Close()
  Dim strSQL As String
  '
  ' we want to update .DatePrinted only if the report is really printed on Paper, not on Print Preview mode on Screen:
  '
  '
  ' not work, always true on Screen or true printer:
  'if(Me.Printer.DeviceName = "HP Laser Printer") Then
  '
  ' not work, this is always true:
  '
  if(Me.CurrentView = 5) Then
    strSQL = "UPDATE tblMainOrders SET DatePrinted = #" & Now() & "# WHERE (OrderID = 12345)"
    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbSeeChanges
  End If
End Sub
```

The shortcoming is that .DatePrinted is always updated, no matter how we select a Preview on Screen (not a true printing),
or printed on a Physical Printer like "HP Laser Printer" on a paper, or PDFCreator as .pdf document, as Report.CurrentView is always 5 (Print Preview).

How can we check if we are really printing to a Physical Printer?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: No. The "physical" printer could as well be a _PDF_ or _OneNote_ virtual printer, as could a physical printer be offline while the printer server buffers the print - which may never be printed to paper. Even if you succeed printing the paper invoice, it may end up in the makulator.

Comment: I did a quick test. Get same result. If users are allowed to open to Preview and then print or not, I don't see any way to control this SQL update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally worked out a pure VBA way with **5 steps** after some long days of trying, without dll required, very happy to share with you.

Added `Me.Pages` consideration to work with the case with more than 1 page/report.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
'
' 1. define some variables:
'    mlReportPageEventsCount: number of occurred Report_Page() events
'    mbPreviewOnly: key indicating if screen preview only
'
Private mlReportPageEventsCount As Long
Private mbPreviewOnly As Boolean

'
' 2. initialize, although this is done by default during compiling:
'
Private Sub Report_Open(ByRef Cancel As Integer)
'
  mlReportPageEventsCount = 0
  mbPreviewOnly = False
'
End Sub

'
' 3. this occurs only if on screen preview,
'    but not for invisible printer submission (no screen used):
'
Private Sub Report_Activate()
'
  mbPreviewOnly = True
'
End Sub

'
' 4. this is done for both preview and each printing,
'    once per page at the maximum, again and again
'    if you print more than once from the preview window:
'
Private Sub Report_Page()
'
  mlReportPageEventsCount = mlReportPageEventsCount + 1
'
' here if the current event takes place more than
' the total number of the pages of the report,
' we have done both the preview and sending to printer
' from the preview,
' so negate the preview only key:
'
  If (mlReportPageEventsCount > Me.Pages) Then
    mbPreviewOnly = False
  End If
'
End Sub

'
' 5. use the preview only key to perform our fixed task:
'
Private Sub Report_Close()
'
  Dim strSQL As String
  '
  ' we want to update .DatePrinted only if the report is really printed on Paper,
  ' not on Print Preview mode on Screen:
  '
  '
  ' not work, always true on Screen or true printer:
  'if(Me.Printer.DeviceName = "HP Laser Printer") Then
  '
  ' not work, this is always true:
  '
  'If (Me.CurrentView = 5) Then
  '
  If (mbPreviewOnly) Then
    MsgBox "We have only previewed the report on screen."
  Else
    MsgBox "We have printed the report. So we do a updating..."
    
    strSQL = "UPDATE tblMainOrders SET DatePrinted = #" & Now() & "# WHERE (OrderID = 12345)"
    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbSeeChanges
  End If
'
End Sub
```

The initial idea comes from [Karl Donaubauer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6ed9bb2a-b754-4756-a4c6-23175a40fc14/access-2010-how-to-determine-if-a-report-was-actually-printed-used-to-work-in-2003?forum=accessdev) of Microsoft Community.

The basic idea is that the `Report_Activate()` event occurs only on Preview Mode using screen. And `Report_Page()` takes place for both preview on Screen and for each printing, again and again.